# Cumulative Sum with Conditions in R

Tags: r

Say I have

```
a <- c(0, 22, 0, 2, 0, 0, 20, 20, 20, 0, 0)
```

I want to do a cumulative sum whereby I minus `5` to each value in `a`, and then add on the previous value.

However, I also have the condition that if `a` becomes less than `0`, I want the cumsum to `0` and if `a` becomes greater than `40`, for cumsum to `40`.

So, I want to get

```
(0, 17, 12, 9, 4, 0, 15, 30, 40, 35, 30)
```

Can anyone help? I've been trying out a lot of things for a few hours now!

@Holger, that method doesn't always work.
So if I add in a couple of extra zeros it does not come with the right solution

```
a <- c(0, 22, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 20, 20, 0, 0)
```

gives

```
 0 17 12  9  4  0  1  7 22 37 52 47 42
```

Comment: Why is this answer off now? The result should always be less than 40. And I don't understand why a 1 appears in the result vector at one point. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 3):

Here are some alternatives:

**1) Loop** Create a one line loop like this:

```
b <- a; for(i in seq_along(b)[-1]) b[i] <- min(40, max(0, a[i] - 5 + b[i-1]))
b
## [1]  0 17 12  9  4  0 15 30 40 35 30
```

**2) Reduce**

```
f <- function(b, a) min(40, max(0, a - 5 + b))
Reduce(f, a, acc = TRUE)
## [1]  0 17 12  9  4  0 15 30 40 35 30
```

**3) recursion**  This recursive solution will be limited to inputs which are not too long.

```
rec <- function(a) {
   n <- length(a)
   if (n <= 1) a
   else {
     rec.hd <- Recall(a[-n])
     c(rec.hd, min(40, max(0, rec.hd[n-1] + a[n] - 5)))
   }
}
rec(a)
## [1]  0 17 12  9  4  0 15 30 40 35 30
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
cumsum_up_low <- function(a, d=5, up=40, low=0 ){
  out = rep(0, length(a))
  out[1] = a[1]*(a[1]>=0 && a[1]<=40) + 0*(a[1]<0) + 40*(a[1] > 40)
  for(i in 2:length(a)){
    if(out[i-1] + a[i] - d > low && out[i-1] + a[i] - d < up){
      out[i] = out[i-1] + a[i] - d
    } else if(out[i-1] + a[i] - d <= low){
      out[i] = 0          
    } else out[i] = 40
  }
  out
}

cumsum_up_low(a, d=5, up=40, low=0)
# [1]  0 17 12  9  4  0 15 30 40 35 30
```

### For long vectors

```
a <- sample(a, 1e6, TRUE)
system.time(cumsum_up_low(a))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   3.59    0.00    3.59 
library(compiler)
cumsum_up_low_compiled <- cmpfun(cumsum_up_low)
system.time(cumsum_up_low_compiled(a))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.28    0.00    0.28
```

### For a really long vectors

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('
NumericVector cumsum_up_low_cpp(NumericVector a, double d, double up, double low) {
  NumericVector out(a.size());
  out[0] = a[0];
  for(int i=1; i<a.size(); i++){
    if(out[i-1] + a[i] - d > low & out[i-1] + a[i] - d < up){
      out[i] = out[i-1] + a[i] - d;
    } else if(out[i-1] + a[i] - d <= low){
      out[i] = 0;          
    } else out[i] = 40;
  }
  return out;
}')

a <- sample(a, 5e6, replace = TRUE)
system.time(cumsum_up_low_compiled(a, d=5, up=40, low=0))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   1.45    0.00    1.46 
system.time(cumsum_up_low_cpp(a, d=5, up=40, low=0))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.04    0.02    0.05
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Reduce` to get the cumulative sum and combine this with `max` and `min` or `pmin` and `pmax` to get the bounds.

It is unclear whether you want to use the 0 and 40 in your cumulative summation or if you want bound the variable afterwards. Below, I've provided both possibilities.

Bound within the summation:

```
Reduce(function(x, y) min(max(x + y - 5, 0), 40), a, 0, accumulate=TRUE)
[1]  0  0 17 12  9  4  0 15 30 40 35 30
```

Bound after the summation

```
pmin(pmax(Reduce(function(x, y) x + y - 5, a, 0, accumulate=TRUE), 0), 40)
[1]  0  0 12  7  4  0  0  9 24 39 34 29
```

Comment: Excellent. So to have my "-5" then I would do
Reduce(function(x, y) pmin(pmax(x + y - 5, 0), 40), b, 0, accumulate=TRUE)

Out of interest, how come there is the "0" after the "b"? I want this to be the same length as my vector b so presumably I can remove this to achieve this!

Comment: Ah, I missed the subtracting 5 part, I'll revise my answer. The 0 near the end is the "y" in the anonymous function `function(x, y)`. It is a filler that allows for the cumulative summation.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not the efficient way to do this, but it might be easiest to understand:

```
a <- c(0, 22, 0, 2, 0, 0, 20, 20, 20, 0, 0)

## Initialize another vector just like a
c <- a


## Do it easy-to-understand'ly in a for loop:
for (i in seq_along(a)){
  b <- a[i]
  if (i>1) {
    b <- b+c[i-1]
    b <- b-5
  } 
  if (b<0) b <- 0
  if (b>40) b <- 40
  c[i] <- b
  print(c[i])
}
```

Try to figure out each part, and if you need help, lemme know!