# R: How can I replace the for loop (`cumsum with condition`) below with apply function?

Tags: r

I have the following function. I really dislike the fact that I am expressing it in the form of a for loop. Would it be possible to express it using an `apply` function ?

Note that `x` is just a vector as below.

`c(0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 
0)`

```
testing <- function(x){
  x_cumsum <- 0
  for(i in 1:length(x)){
    x_cumsum = x_cumsum + x[i]
    if(x_cumsum < 0){
      x_cumsum = 0
    }    
  }
  return(x_cumsum)
}
```

Please note that this is kind of similar to `cumsum` function but there is a condition that resets `x_cumsum` to 0 whenever it is smaller than `0`.

Comment: Instead of `apply`  why not use the built-in function `cumsum` ?

Comment: there is a condition in there, which resets the `x_cumsum` to 0. That's why i cannot use `cumsum`

Comment: [Cumulative Sum with Conditions in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40996306/cumulative-sum-with-conditions-in-r); [Conditional cumsum with reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34531568/conditional-cumsum-with-reset), and links therein.

Comment: [Cumulative sum until maximum reached, then repeat from zero in the next row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15466880/cumulative-sum-until-maximum-reached-then-repeat-from-zero-in-the-next-row?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
x_cumsum<-0;
lapply(x,function(y) x_cumsum<-max(0,x_cumsum+y))
# 0 for your sample input.
```

Comment: Sorry, my function only returns 1 value. and it returns value `1` using my example input above.