# efficient cumsum problem and can't go below zero

Tags: r, performance, dplyr, data.table, cumsum

I'm looking for a way to accomplish the following as efficiently as possible as I'm working with large datasets (~7 million rows in total). A `dplyr` vs `data.table` comparison would be really helpful. For any day of the year I want to know how much stock is in a given supplier. We know how much is in stock on the 1st day of the year and it is a matter of creating a rolling sum from that based on whether stock is moved `from` or `to` another supplier. Each row represents one piece of stock being moved. If there's an `NA` this just means theres an external move `from` or `to` and is processed the same way. Stock can't fall below 0 though (see supplier `a` below) and if this happens in any of the suppliers, the cumulative sum must be set to zero and the sum continued on. I dont think a wide format solution makes sense here as I've over 100000 suppliers.

Small example:

```
    library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame(date = sample(seq.Date(from = as.Date("01/01/2018", "%d/%m/%Y"), 
                                 to=as.Date("30/01/2018", "%d/%m/%Y"), by = "day"), 20, replace = TRUE),
                 from = sample(letters[c(1:4, 12)], 20, replace = TRUE),
                 to = sample(letters[c(1:4, 14, 20)], 20, replace = TRUE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(date)
df[14, 2] <- NA
df[10, 3] <- NA
df[5, 3] <- NA
df[6, 2] <- NA
df
#          date from   to
# 1  2018-01-02    c    t
# 2  2018-01-04    l    c
# 3  2018-01-06    d    n
# 4  2018-01-06    d    t
# 5  2018-01-06    a <NA>
# 6  2018-01-07 <NA>    d
# 7  2018-01-07    b    t
# 8  2018-01-10    b    t
# 9  2018-01-11    l    n
# 10 2018-01-12    c <NA>
# 11 2018-01-14    b    t
# 12 2018-01-16    c    a
# 13 2018-01-19    c    n
# 14 2018-01-22 <NA>    a
# 15 2018-01-23    l    t
# 16 2018-01-23    d    a
# 17 2018-01-23    c    a
# 18 2018-01-23    l    c
# 19 2018-01-25    b    d
# 20 2018-01-26    a    c
```

and the base line stock count for the 1st day of the year for all suppliers:

```
base_line <- data.frame(supplier =c("l", "b", "d",  "c", "a", "n", "t"),

                            count = c(10, 20, 12, 5, 0, 2, 10))
    base_line
    #   supplier count
    # 1        l    10
    # 2        b    20
    # 3        d    12
    # 4        c     5
    # 5        a     0
    # 6        n     2
    # 7        t    10
```

**Desired output** **(count of stock for each day):**

```
            date from   to cumsum_var supplier
1  2018-01-02    c    t         11        t
2  2018-01-06    d    t         12        t
3  2018-01-07    b    t         13        t
4  2018-01-10    b    t         14        t
5  2018-01-14    b    t         15        t
6  2018-01-23    l    t         16        t
7  2018-01-06    d    n          3        n
8  2018-01-11    l    n          4        n
9  2018-01-19    c    n          5        n
10 2018-01-06    a <NA>          0        a note 0, not -1
11 2018-01-16    c    a          1        a
12 2018-01-22 <NA>    a          2        a
13 2018-01-23    d    a          3        a
14 2018-01-23    c    a          4        a
15 2018-01-26    a    c          3        a
16 2018-01-06    d    n         11        d
17 2018-01-06    d    t         10        d
18 2018-01-07 <NA>    d         11        d
19 2018-01-23    d    a         10        d
20 2018-01-25    b    d         11        d
21 2018-01-02    c    t          4        c
22 2018-01-04    l    c          5        c
23 2018-01-12    c <NA>          4        c
24 2018-01-16    c    a          3        c
25 2018-01-19    c    n          2        c
26 2018-01-23    c    a          1        c
27 2018-01-23    l    c          2        c
28 2018-01-26    a    c          3        c
29 2018-01-07    b    t         19        b
30 2018-01-10    b    t         18        b
31 2018-01-14    b    t         17        b
32 2018-01-25    b    d         16        b
33 2018-01-04    l    c          9        l
34 2018-01-11    l    n          8        l
35 2018-01-23    l    t          7        l
36 2018-01-23    l    c          6        l
```

**My approach** was to `filter` both datasets based on supplier, do a `cumsum` and then merge altogether in a list at the end but doesn't incorporate the caveat that stock count can't go below 0 (see problem with `a` in my output).

```
 base_line2 <- data.frame(date = rep(as.Date("31/12/2017", "%d/%m/%Y"), 7),
                         from = c("l", "b", "d",  "c", "a", "n", "t"),
                         from_new = c(10, 20, 12, 5, 0, 2, 10), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#get all suppliers (in real dataset >100000)
vars2 <- c("l", "b", "d",  "c", "a", "n", "t")
#function
my_fun <- function(x) {

  df %>% 
    filter_at(vars(from, to), any_vars(. == {{x}})) %>% 
    mutate(from_new = ifelse(from == {{x}}, -1, 0),
           to_new = ifelse(to == {{x}}, 1, 0)) %>% 
    bind_rows({base_line2 %>% filter(from == {{x}})}) %>% 
    dplyr::arrange(date) %>% 
    mutate(count_test = rowSums(select(., from_new, to_new), na.rm = T),
           cumsum_var = cumsum(count_test))

}

#use function over list
tmp <- lapply(vars2, my_fun)
output = rbindlist(tmp)
output
output %>% 
  filter(date > as.Date("2017-12-31")) 

#          date from   to from_new to_new count_test cumsum_var
# 1  2018-01-04    l    c       -1      0         -1          9
# 2  2018-01-11    l    n       -1      0         -1          8
# 3  2018-01-23    l    t       -1      0         -1          7
# 4  2018-01-23    l    c       -1      0         -1          6
# 5  2018-01-07    b    t       -1      0         -1         19
# 6  2018-01-10    b    t       -1      0         -1         18
# 7  2018-01-14    b    t       -1      0         -1         17
# 8  2018-01-25    b    d       -1      0         -1         16
# 9  2018-01-06    d    n       -1      0         -1         11
# 10 2018-01-06    d    t       -1      0         -1         10
# 11 2018-01-07 <NA>    d       NA      1          1         11
# 12 2018-01-23    d    a       -1      0         -1         10
# 13 2018-01-25    b    d        0      1          1         11
# 14 2018-01-02    c    t       -1      0         -1          4
# 15 2018-01-04    l    c        0      1          1          5
# 16 2018-01-12    c <NA>       -1     NA         -1          4
# 17 2018-01-16    c    a       -1      0         -1          3
# 18 2018-01-19    c    n       -1      0         -1          2
# 19 2018-01-23    c    a       -1      0         -1          1
# 20 2018-01-23    l    c        0      1          1          2
# 21 2018-01-26    a    c        0      1          1          3
# 22 2018-01-06    a <NA>       -1     NA         -1         -1
# 23 2018-01-16    c    a        0      1          1          0
# 24 2018-01-22 <NA>    a       NA      1          1          1
# 25 2018-01-23    d    a        0      1          1          2
# 26 2018-01-23    c    a        0      1          1          3
# 27 2018-01-26    a    c       -1      0         -1          2
# 28 2018-01-06    d    n        0      1          1          3
# 29 2018-01-11    l    n        0      1          1          4
# 30 2018-01-19    c    n        0      1          1          5
# 31 2018-01-02    c    t        0      1          1         11
# 32 2018-01-06    d    t        0      1          1         12
# 33 2018-01-07    b    t        0      1          1         13
# 34 2018-01-10    b    t        0      1          1         14
# 35 2018-01-14    b    t        0      1          1         15
# 36 2018-01-23    l    t        0      1          1         16
```

I think a `data.table` approach here instead might improve efficiency or a better `dplyr` approach altogether? Does anyone have a suggestion on keeping stock at 0 or above efficiently?

thanks

Comment: sorry good spot, was just missing the `l`s, updated now, the `l`s are at the bottom now

Comment: note supplier `l`s are at the bottom of my "desired output" but at the top of my own approach output. Order of suppliers in final output doesn't matter as long as they're grouped together!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option:

```
setDT(base_line)[, date := as.Date("2017-12-31")]
DT <- rbindlist(list(
        base_line,
        df[!is.na(from), .(date, supplier=from, count=-1L)],
        df[!is.na(to), .(date, supplier=to, count=1L)]),
    use.names=TRUE)
setorder(DT, supplier, date)


library(Rcpp)
cppFunction("
IntegerVector csreset (IntegerVector grp, IntegerVector v) {
    int sz = v.size(), cs = 0;
    IntegerVector res(sz);

    cs = v[0];
    res[0] = cs;
    for (int i=1; i<sz; i++) {
        if (grp[i] != grp[i-1]) {
            cs = 0;
        }

        if (cs + v[i] < 0) {
            cs = 0;
        } else {
            cs += v[i];
        }
        res[i] = cs;
    }

    return(res);
}
")

DT[, .(supplier, date, csreset(rleid(supplier), count))]
```

output:

```
    supplier       date count
 1:        a 2017-12-31     0
 2:        a 2018-01-06     0
 3:        a 2018-01-16     1
 4:        a 2018-01-22     2
 5:        a 2018-01-23     3
 6:        a 2018-01-23     4
 7:        a 2018-01-26     3
 8:        b 2017-12-31    20
 9:        b 2018-01-07    19
10:        b 2018-01-10    18
11:        b 2018-01-14    17
12:        b 2018-01-25    16
13:        c 2017-12-31     5
14:        c 2018-01-02     4
15:        c 2018-01-04     5
16:        c 2018-01-12     4
17:        c 2018-01-16     3
18:        c 2018-01-19     2
19:        c 2018-01-23     1
20:        c 2018-01-23     2
21:        c 2018-01-26     3
22:        d 2017-12-31    12
23:        d 2018-01-06    11
24:        d 2018-01-06    10
25:        d 2018-01-07    11
26:        d 2018-01-23    10
27:        d 2018-01-25    11
28:        l 2017-12-31    10
29:        l 2018-01-04     9
30:        l 2018-01-11     8
31:        l 2018-01-23     7
32:        l 2018-01-23     6
33:        n 2017-12-31     2
34:        n 2018-01-06     3
35:        n 2018-01-11     4
36:        n 2018-01-19     5
37:        t 2017-12-31    10
38:        t 2018-01-02    11
39:        t 2018-01-06    12
40:        t 2018-01-07    13
41:        t 2018-01-10    14
42:        t 2018-01-14    15
43:        t 2018-01-23    16
    supplier       date count
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
df <- fread("date from   to
2018-01-02    c    t
2018-01-04    l    c
2018-01-06    d    n
2018-01-06    d    t
2018-01-06    a   NA
2018-01-07   NA    d
2018-01-07    b    t
2018-01-10    b    t
2018-01-11    l    n
2018-01-12    c   NA
2018-01-14    b    t
2018-01-16    c    a
2018-01-19    c    n
2018-01-22   NA    a
2018-01-23    l    t
2018-01-23    d    a
2018-01-23    c    a
2018-01-23    l    c
2018-01-25    b    d
2018-01-26    a    c")[, date := as.Date(date, format="%Y-%m-%d")]

base_line <- data.frame(supplier =c("l", "b", "d",  "c", "a", "n", "t"),
    count = c(10, 20, 12, 5, 0, 2, 10))
```

If its still too slow, we can try another approach.

Comment: thanks, this looks like the type of solution i was after except that I dont think the `cumsum` is working correctly, if we change `b` to `0` in `base_line` and rerun it, it doesn't give the expected answer `base_line <- data.frame(supplier =c("l", "b", "d",  "c", "a", "n", "t"),
                        count = c(10, 0, 12, 5, 0, 2, 10))`. The answer for `b` should then be `0` on each date?

Comment: yes thats what I was worried about too. would these help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40996306/cumulative-sum-with-conditions-in-r

Comment: @user63230 i have added a Rcpp function to address both the recursive nature of the problem and the speed issue

Comment: thanks for this excellent answer, one minor issue is that the very first count (first row) is set to zero in the output so if we change `base_line` `a` to say `10`, the first line is `0` instead of `10`? Only a minor issue though as I don't need that value in this example

Comment: Sorry I missed out 1 line. Have added it back